# How to get the expansion of value using Decimal() in python?

Tags: python

I am using the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.getcontext) function to get the value after expansion.

When I am trying to use the Decimal method with the number: `1e-6`,
I see the following expansion

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1e-6')
Decimal('0.000001')
```

But when I try it with the number: `1e-7`, I am not getting the correct expansion

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('1e-7')
Decimal('1E-7')
```

Could anyone help me to get the expansion using **Decimal** function when the number is having exponents -7 or even smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is doing the conversion right however it is merely not printing it. Note that how the `e` changed to `E`

```
   v =Decimal('1e-7')
   print("{:.10f}".format(v))
```

this would output

```
   0.0000001000
```

[Python formatting](https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/)

Comment: Yes, it looks good. But if I'd add/subtract 2 values. Let's say `1e-6` and `1e-7` then it is giving the correct result by using the following code

`val = "{:.10f}".format(Decimal('3.47e-7')); sum = Decimal(val)+ Decimal(val) = Decimal('0.0000038170')`

But when I tried to multiply them then not getting in correct format

`mul = Decimal(first_val)* Decimal(second_val) = Decimal('1.20409000E-12')`

So dont we have a proper way to achive it

Comment: @AbinashBiswal _It's the same number!_ You don't need to worry about the _internal representation_ of the number or its default string representation. Very small numbers are written in scientific notation because it's a pain to count all those zeros before the significant figures. If you want it in a fixed format, _format it_ to the fixed format like you did using `"{:10f}".format()`

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for your response.